func to return value from key in dictionary - python
I want to return the value only when providing the key to a function. Using below, if the key is provided, the linked value should be returned. If the key does not exist, then return 'Fruit Not Found'.
Steps:

create empty list to append values

iterate key, value from dict

if given parameter is a key, append to list. else return not found

return list value


code:
fruits = {"Apple": 8, "Orange": 7, "Lemon": 9, "Lime": 5, "Banana": 20}

def fruit_price(x):

    price = [] 

    for k,v in fruits.items():
    
        if x in k:
            price.append(x)
        else:
            print('Fruit Not Found')

    return price


fruit_price('Lemon')

Exp output:
9


What does your code do step by step? Basic debugging skills... You have about 3 mistakes within 3 lines.

What are you going to use a list for if you only want to return exactly one value?

if x in k well the nonexistent variable x will for sure no be in k.

@Cincinnatus x exists…!?

You don't need to create a loop. Square brackets are used to get the value from the dictionary. You can use try-except constructions. If the KeyError occurs in the 'try' block that there is no value for the key, then the code from the 'except' block will be executed
fruits = {"Apple": 8, "Orange": 7, "Lemon": 9, "Lime": 5, "Banana": 20}

def fruit_price(fruit: str):
    try: 
        return fruits[fruit]
    except KeyError:
        return fruit + ' is not found'

fruit_price('Lemon')
fruit_price('Melon')

Output:
9
Melon is not found

Actually you can just use get() method, if the value for the key doesn't exist, it returns 'None' or whatever you want
fruit1 = 'Lemon'
fruit2 = 'Melon'
# The first argument is a "key"
# The second argument "default" is what the method returns if the value for the key doesn't exist
# It is not necessary to pass the value of the second argument
# Because, by default, the second argument is None
fruits.get(fruit1, fruit1 + ' is not found')
fruits.get(fruit2, fruit2 + ' is not found')
fruits.get(fruit2)

Output:
9
Melon is not found
None


You should do specifically except KeyError; bare except clauses are bad practice.

You're on the right path there with .get, only that you want it to return "Fruit Not Found" instead of None…

You are right. My editor pointed out that the function accepts default only as int

fruits = {"Apple": 8, "Orange": 7, "Lemon": 9, "Lime": 5, "Banana": 20}

def fruit_price(x):
    found_fruit = ''
    for fruit in fruits:
        if fruit == x:
            found_fruit = x
    if found_fruit != '':
        return fruits[found_fruit]
    else:
        print('Fruit Not Found')


print(fruit_price('Lemon'))

the above code can solve your problem.
